# Avoid same option selected multiple times using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two tables Table1 and Table2.
Each table contains `<select>` tag and the options and their values were same.

Now I want to check for each table, there any option exists more than one times. If yes then alert option already selected.

My code is:

```
$('#table1 tr').each(function() {
    $(this).find('select').change(function() { //alert($(this).val())
        if ($('option[value=' + $(this).val() + ']:selected').length > 1) {
            alert('option is already selected');
            $(this).val($(this).find("option:first").val());
        }
    });
});

$('#table2 tr').each(function() {
    $(this).find('select').change(function() { //alert($(this).val())
        if ($('option[value=' + $(this).val() + ']:selected').length > 1) {
            alert('option is already selected');
            $(this).val($(this).find("option:first").val());
        }
    });
});
```

When  select same in first table and second table it will alert option already selected. What's wrong with my code?

You can test the code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/tu6ce8ab/).

Comment: Both of them.(Each table and each row)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem was that you were selecting all options (table1 + 2) whereas you should have selected options belonging to the current table, such as below.

```
$('#table1 tr').each(function() {                                       
    $(this).find('select').change(function(){//alert($(this).val())
        if( $('#table1').find('select option[value='+$(this).val()+']:selected').length>1){
            alert('option is already selected');
            $(this).val($(this).find("option:first").val());   
        }
    });
});

$('#table2 tr').each(function() {                                       
    $(this).find('select').change(function(){//alert($(this).val())
        if($('#table2').find('select option[value='+$(this).val()+']:selected').length>1){
            alert('option is already selected');
            $(this).val($(this).find("option:first").val());   
        }
    });
});
```

Demo@[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tu6ce8ab/2/)

**Edit:**

A slightly better version:

```
// Have a class if you will, for your 2 tables (or more) which would avoid the use of ID's as you may not even need them
// <table class="grouped-select" ... >
// and then do:
// $('.grouped-select').find('select').on('change', function() {
// or just use tag selector
$('table').find('select').on('change', function() {
    //Cache jQuery references that you'd reuse over and over
    var $this = $(this);
    if( $this.closest('table').find('select option[value=' + $this.val() + ']:selected').length > 1) {
        alert('option is already selected');
        $this.val($this.find("option:first").val());
    }
});
```

Comment: Do you think `each` is necessary here? Can be optimized

Comment: @Tushar - Rose need only answer not the best

Comment: @JqueryKing I feel that BEST answer should be accepted and not WORKING answer

Answer (score 3):

You are selecting all the `options` instead of in the current table.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tu6ce8ab/8/)**

*Change*

```
$('option[value=' + $(this).val() + ']:selected')
```

*To*

```
$(this).closest('table').find('option[value='+$(this).val()+']:selected')
```

You can make single handler instead of multiple for each row and further simplify and optimize code like this.

```
$('select').change(function () {
    if ($(this).closest('table').find('option[value=' + $(this).val() + ']:selected').length > 1)
    {
        alert('option is already selected');
        $(this).val($(this).find("option:first").val());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you change your if statements to be specific to each table that should do it. So:

```
if($('#table1 tr option[value='+$(this).val()+']:selected').length>1)
```

and `if($('#table2 tr option[value='+$(this).val()+']:selected').length>1)`

and actually if you changed the selector to parent selectors you could use just the one code block of any table of this kind:

```
$('table').each(function() {
    $(this).find('select').change(function() {

        if ($(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().find($('tr option[value=' + $(this).val() + ']:selected')).length > 1) {
            alert('option is already selected');
            $(this).val($(this).find("option:first").val()); //put it back to 1
        }
    });
});
```

In this one it loops through all tables and on the change event finds the table its part of (so the id doesn't matter) and then runs your check as you had it before.

And even better than that you could use the .closest selector

```
$('table').each(function() {
    $(this).find('select').change(function() {

        if ($(this).closest('table').find($('tr option[value=' + $(this).val() + ']:selected')).length > 1) {
            alert('option is already selected');
            $(this).val($(this).find("option:first").val()); //put it back to 1
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#table1 tr').each(function() {
    $(this).find('select').change(function() { //alert($(this).val())
        if ($('#table1 tr td select  option[value=' + $(this).val() + ']:selected').length > 1) {
            alert('option is already selected');
            $(this).val($(this).find("option:first").val());
        }
    });
});

$('#table2 tr').each(function() {
    $(this).find('select').change(function() { //alert($(this).val())
        if ($('#table2 tr td select option[value=' + $(this).val() + ']:selected').length > 1) {
            alert('option is already selected');
            $(this).val($(this).find("option:first").val());
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with **attribute selector** in jquery

```
$('[id ^= "table"] tr').find('select').change(function() {
    if ($(this).closest('table').find('option[value=' + $(this).val() + ']:selected').length > 1) {
        alert('option is already selected');
        $(this).val($(this).find("option:first").val());
    }
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/tu6ce8ab/5/)

Comment: @Tushar - Why others use .each() loop this is unwanted for this answer right

Comment: YES! You are right. But still they have got UP-VOTES