# how to make sure that selected options are different before submit the form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

```
        <select class="distinctrank" name="rank[]"  required>
            <option value="">Select</option>
            <option value="1">A</option>
            <option value="2">B</option>
            <option value="3">C</option>
        </select>

        <select class="distinctrank" name="rank[]"  required>
            <option value="">Select</option>
            <option value="1">A</option>
            <option value="2">B</option>
            <option value="3">C</option>
        </select>

        <select class="distinctrank" name="rank[]"  required>
            <option value="">Select</option>
            <option value="1">A</option>
            <option value="2">B</option>
            <option value="3">C</option>
        </select>
```

I am trying to prevent the user to select the same option twice

EX:

- value 1 -> B
- value 2 -> C
- value 3 -> A

But not allow

- value 1 -> B
- value 2 -> B
- value 3 -> A

I can't use this: [answer](http://jsfiddle.net/dactivo/keDDr/)
because I have 8 `<select>` with 8 `<option>`and the user is allow to change his/her option.

Unfortunately, I can't use a single select set to "multiple".
I found this answer just now, but since I don't jquery or Javascript well, I can't make it work without the select tag inside a table:
[Here is the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30570981/avoid-same-option-selected-multiple-times-using-jquery)

**UPDATE:** 
I found a better way to do it, but I am having some problems.
I tried to modify this code: [with input tags](http://jsfiddle.net/j952T/) to make it work with select tags.  The problem that I am facing now is that every time you select the same option twice, the error "**Please enter a Unique Value**" show up (I do want to see it, when the user select the same value twice or more) and when you change the value the "**Please enter a Unique Value**" does go away. But, It keep a "**this field is required**" warning behind (when a click a new select tag).  So, "**this field is required**" doesn't go away until the user pick an option for all select tag. 
Here is the Jquery code:

```
 jQuery.e

 jQuery.validator.addMethod("notEqualToGroup", function(value, element, options) {
  // get all the elements passed here with the same class
  var elems = $(element).parents('form').find(options[0]);
  // the value of the current element
  var valueToCompare = value;
  // count
  var matchesFound = 0;
  // loop each element and compare its value with the current value
  // and increase the count every time we find one
  jQuery.each(elems, function() {
      thisVal = $(this).val();
      if (thisVal === valueToCompare) {
          matchesFound++;
      }
     });
    // count should be either 0 or 1 max
    if (this.optional(element) || matchesFound <= 1) {
      //elems.removeClass('error');
      return true;
    } else {
      //elems.addClass('error');
    }
  }, jQuery.validator.format("Please enter a Unique Value."))

   // validate form    
  $("#signupform").validate({


  rules: {
      'rank[]': {
          required: true,
          notEqualToGroup: ['.distinctrank']
      },
  },
});
```

Comment: You **cannot** have three `select` elements with the same `name`.  The jQuery Validate plugin will **not** work if this is the case.

Comment: So, what happens if I have an array of select tags, which I do, with 8 tags or more.  How can I keep track of it?

Comment: I'm just telling you that this plugin will not work properly if you use the same `name` on more than one element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code...

```
rules: {
  'rank[]': { // <-- will only match one of your three
      required: true, ....
```

You cannot have three different `select` element all share the same `name`, in your case, `rank[]`.

The jQuery Validate plugin requires that every form data input element contain a unique `name`.  It's how the plugin keeps track of the form inputs, and there is no workaround for this.  You'll have to include an index or change the `name`.

```
rules: {
    'rank[1]': { 
        // rules
    },
    'rank[2]': { 
        // rules
    },
    'rank[3]': { 
        // rules
    }
}
```

If the same rules are used on all three, then you can use the `.rules()` method to apply them all at once...

```
$("#signupform").validate({ // plugin initialization
    // other rules & options
});

$('[name^="rank"]').each(function() {
    $(this).rules('add', {
        required: true,
        notEqualToGroup: ['.distinctrank']
    });
});
```

`$('[name^="rank"]')` matches all elements that have a `name` that "starts with" `rank`.  Then `.each()` applies the rule to every instance matched by the selector.

Comment: So, I change the name for each select tag, but the "this field is required" doesn't go away when I click a new select tag.  PS: "This field is required" only appear where the same value were selected, for example, if select 1 and 2 were same options, but you click on the select #7 or #5, the "this fields is required" appear under the select tag #2 (even if it does has a option selected) Thank you

Comment: @AMaduro, if you want to make one `select` required from a group of `select` elements, then you would use the `require_from_group` rule which is part of [the `additional-methods.js` file](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.14.0/additional-methods.js) for this plugin.

Comment: Thankkk you, I will try it, and let you know ;)

Answer (score 4):

I wonder if you could simply use a single select set to "multiple"...

```
<select multiple class="form-control" name="rank[]">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="1">A</option>
    <option value="2">B</option>
    <option value="3">C</option>
</select>
```

It seems appropriate :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('select').change(function() {
    self = $(this);
    choosen = $(this).val();

    $('select').not(self).each(function() {

      if ($(this).val() == choosen) {

        // $(this).prop('disabled', true);
        alert('Option is already selected');
        $(self).val($(this).find("option:first").val());
      }

    });

  });
});
```

This is actually partial implementation of code you found in another answer. Commented line would disable already selected options, but... then users can't change their minds... However i would probably use that commented line `(edit:probably not, it causes other problems)`, rather than annoying alerts -> because, with alerts - if user tries to change his mind - user experience is not so great, again...

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/dq9j4s32/2